# Receive too many incoming sms

Tags: twilio

I am developing an app where the signup process involves sending sms to a twilio number in order to verify the users phone number. In testing this, it seems twilio is no longer receiving text messages from my number. Is there a way to whitelist my number so I can send as many texts as I want to the twilio number while I am developing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this, Twilio does not limit the number or rate of incoming SMS messages:

> **Inbound Calls and SMS**
>
> *Twilio places no limitation on the rate at which a number can receive inbound calls or SMS messages. One thing to note here, though, is that
>   Twilio will make an HTTP request to the request URL for each call and
>   message received at your Twilio number. Therefore, please make sure
>   your server is capable of handling the load if you are expecting a
>   large amount of concurrent inbound traffic.*

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/what-are-the-limits-on-outbound-calls-and-sms-messages-per-second

If you are running into problems, as the above indicates, you should make sure you server is not the problem first.

Are you having a problem sending too many SMS's or receiving too many SMS's? If its a sending problem, what are you sending the SMS's from?

Comment: To add to this answer, you can use the Twilio Monitor to see if errors are happening: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts